# Form select not saving in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, iad

I'm working on an HTML view for iAd Producer. I'm trying to add a list of sentences which have alternative words students can choose and to save those values to localStorage as they change and repopulate the selects with those values when the page is revisited.

I'm adapting some code I wrote which works fine to save multiple input boxes on a page. But I have strange behaviour when trying to use it with multiple selects. Basically, no matter which order the answers are completed in, only the last chosen value is being stored. When the page is revisited, the code attempts to put that value in each select. This, of course, fails for the two selects which do not have corresponding values.

I cannot see why this is happening and hope someone can spot the obvious. Thanks.

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var uniqueId = "FC2-U2-A-P29";

$(document).ready(function () {
   function onStartup() {
    $.each( $("select"), function() {
        if (localStorage[$(this).attr("value")+uniqueId]) {
        $(this).val(localStorage[$(this).attr("value")+uniqueId]);
        }  
    });
}
onStartup();  
});

$('.drop').change(function () {
localStorage[$(this).attr("value")+uniqueId] = $(this).val();
});
</script>   

<form>
<label class="number">1.</label>
    <label class="text">Breakfast is the </label>
    <select name="select1" class="drop">
            <option value="blank">Choose a word</option>
            <option value="one1">one</option>
            <option value="first1">first</option>
    </select>
    <label class="text"> meal of the day.</label>
<br>
<label class="number">2.</label>
    <label class="text">I always eat </label>
    <select name="select2" class="drop">
            <option value="blank">Choose a word</option>
            <option value="three2">three</option>
            <option value="third2">third</option>
    </select>
    <label class="text"> meals a day.</label>
<br>
<label class="number">3.</label>
    <label name="select3" class="text">My football team is in</label>
    <select class="drop">
            <option value="blank">Choose a word</option>
            <option value="two3">two</option>
            <option value="second3">second</option>
    </select>
    <label class="text"> place in the league.</label>
<br>      
<button class="clearButton" onclick="clearAnswers()">Clear&nbsp;</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function clearAnswers() {
$.each( $("select"), function() {
    if (localStorage[$(this).attr("value")+uniqueId]) {
        localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr("value")+uniqueId);
        $(this).val("blank");
    }
    location.reload();
});
}
</script>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle.net to demonstrate your problem & expected outcome

Comment: Have you tried appending the `$(this).val();` to the local storage instead of assigning a new value to it each time the `select` changes?

Comment: despite making the changes all suggested below, I've not been able to make any values save into localStorage at all. Can anyone suggest why with the code above one value is saved but not the other two?

Comment: @gerrytan: Here you go... sorry never done it before so didn't realise it was so easy to do. https://jsfiddle.net/k1mnLynd/

Answer (score 1):

The probable reason for which this code fails in select is because of the following :

```
$.each( $("select"), function() {
    if (localStorage[$(this).attr("value")+uniqueId]) { //select doesn't have any attribute value.
    $(this).val(localStorage[$(this).attr("value")+uniqueId]);
    }  
});
```

Select tag doesn't have any value attribute. I think `.val()` is what you need here. If you look at the code, you are basically iterating on select tag and checking `value` attribute(which doesn't exist) of select. Try changing it to .val() and then try.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and nothing at all saves in local storage when the page is reloaded. Also, this still leaves the question as to why only one value is being stored in my original code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To save and load stuff from localstorage use:

```
localStorage.setItem(<key>, <value>);
```

and

```
localStorage.getItem(<key>);
```

Comment: sorry, this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is invalid.

Change `$(this).attr("value")+uniqueId` with `$("option:selected",this ).text()+uniqueId;` in all occurrences.

Comment: thanks for attempting an answer. Using this nothing was saved in local storage using this code.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

The first one is that you should use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`.

The second one is that the code to add the values in localStorage is executed before the DOM is created fully, so the selects dont exist yet. To overcome this you need to bind the change event on document.ready ( aka `$(function() { });` ).

I've made a pastebin with the modified code: http://jsbin.com/jubijuyatu/2/

Comment: I appreciate you modifying the code and making a pastern. Did you manage to get this to store any values. Each time I reload it, it resets to defaults rather than shows any stored values. I also tried the code in iAd Producer and was not able to get the values to save and reload.